# Monotone subsets of uncountable plane sets

Tags: set-theory, infinite-combinatorics

Let $S$ be an uncountable set of points in the Euclidean plane. Define a subset of $S$ to be upward-monotone if every two points determine a line with non-negative slope, and downward-monotone if every two points determine a line with negative or infinite slope. It follows from the [Erdős–Dushnik–Miller theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s%E2%80%93Dushnik%E2%80%93Miller_theorem) that one or more of the following three things happens:

- $S$ contains an uncountable upward-monotone subset
- $S$ contains an uncountable downward-monotone subset
- $S$ contains both a countably-infinite upward-monotone subset and a countably-infinite downward-monotone subset

(This can be viewed as an infinite version of the [Erdős–Szekeres theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s%E2%80%93Szekeres_theorem) on the existence of square-root-sized monotone subsets of finite sets of points in the plane.)

My question concerns sets $S$ that satisfy only the third possibility: $S$ does not have an uncountable monotone subset but does have countable monotone subsets in both directions. Is it known that there exist or that there do not exist sets $S$ for which this is true? If they are known to exist, how can they be constructed? Alternatively, are both the existence and the non-existence of such a set $S$ known to be consistent?

Comment: I think the Open Coloring Axiom implies that no such set exists? (If we make infinite slope part of upward-monotone instead, we get that downward-monotone is an open condition - and I don't think that rephrasing of the problem alters the answer.)

Comment: Euclidean plane has neither up nor down. Cartesian plane ....

Comment: I think the continuum hypothesis implies that such an $S$ exists. The key ingredient is that every upward-monotone set in included in the graph of a (non-strictly) increasing function $\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ that is continuous except for countably many jumps, while downward-monotone sets are included in inverses of decreasing such functions. Since there are (under CH) only aleph_1 such functions, one can build the required $S$ by an induction of $\aleph_1$ steps. Step $\xi$ puts a point into $S$ that isn't on the graph of any of the first $\xi$ of the relevant functions.

Comment: @AndreasBlass: Very nice! Your argument also shows (unconditionally) that there is a subset $S$ of $\mathbb R^2$ with $|S| = \mathfrak{c}$ such that any upward-monotone or downward-monotone subset of $S$ has size $<\!\mathfrak{c}$.

Comment: @WillBrian: you say "unconditionally," but the argument assumes that some uncountable set can be well-ordered.

Comment: @RichardStanley: The factory settings for my brain have the Axiom of Choice option activated. Sometimes I am able to turn this option off manually when the need arises, but usually I think of ZFC as my background theory, and an "unconditional" argument means (to me) one that uses no set-theoretic hypotheses beyond ZFC. But your comment raises an interesting question: Is ZF consistent with "every size-$\mathfrak{c}$ subset of $\mathbb R^2$ has a size-$\mathfrak{c}$ subset that is either upward-monotone or downward-monotone"? (I suspect the answer is yes, but I'm not sure.)

Comment: @WillBrian: the situation is similar to the result that assuming ZFC, there exists a poset of size $\mathfrak{c}$ such that every chain and every antichain is countable. (Simply take the intersection of the usual ordering of $\mathbb{R}$ with a well-ordering of $\mathbb{R}$.) Is ZF consistent with the statement that no such poset exists?  I don't know whether this is known.

Comment: @RichardStanley: Yes, this is more or less just the special case of the poset problem for posets of (Dushnik–Miller!) dimension two, and thinking of it that way is how I got to the problem.